# Different behaviour for setInterval if callback is blocked

Tags: javascript, browser, callback, cross-browser

I run much the same code in Firefox 58 and Chrome 63 on Linux

```
count = 0
intv = 0
function f(){
    let a
    console.log('start', performance.now())
    for (let i=0;i<50000000;i++){
        a=i
    }
    if (count % 5 === 0){
        for (let i=0;i<100000000;i++){
            a=i
        }
    }
    console.log('end', performance.now())
    count++
}
function k(){
    intv=setInterval(f, 100)
}
function e(){
    clearInterval(intv)
}

k()
```

the exact value oof two constants may need adjust to make sure 2nd and 3rd callback is blocked
and in Firefox I got

```
start 2657023.3000000003
end 2657123.92
start 2657124.2800000003
end 2657155.84
start 2657224.2
end 2657265.06
start 2657324.62
end 2657363.3000000003
start 2657424.72
end 2657461.6
start 2657524.94
end 2657624.7800000003
```

as you see, every callback since 3rd is 100ms * N from the time 2nd callback is excuted

And in Chrome

```
start 463571.0300000001
end 464149.28
start 464150.49500000005
end 464178.63000000006
start 464178.775
end 464204.61500000005
start 464270.91000000003
end 464308.09
start 464370.94
end 464415.37500000006
start 464470.93500000006
end 464511.48000000004
```

every callback is excuted at 100ms * N from 1st callback

So is one of these two browser implented setInterval wrong or the behaviour of setInterval do depend on implentation?

Comment: Read all about how different browsers handle setTimeout/setInterval, especially where the browser is busy handling other stuff (like, the previous timeout) [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)

Comment: I have read this but don't see anything helpful

Comment: You can find the detailed specification [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html). It allows for additional delays due to the browser being busy or other implementation-dependent reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact behavior of `setInterval`/`setTimeout` depends on implementation. In addition to differences between browsers and context as discussed on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified) ) and in this draft update of [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html#windowtimers) (also cited in comments).

The HTML document includes notes and steps that indicate some standard exactness when using timers should not be expected:

> This API does not guarantee that timers will fire exactly on schedule. Delays due to CPU load, other tasks, etc, are to be expected.

and

> 9. Optionally, wait a further user-agent defined length of time.

The behavior of the particular JavaScript engines can also influence timing:

- run time profiling and optimization of code can alter and improve the speed of particular sections of code over time,
- intermittent garbage collection can slow down code sometimes and not others,
- run time environment can dynamically alter the engines ability to call a timer callback. Timing on a low speed notebook with 30 tabs open may be quite different from that using a high speed processor with a single tab open, no other applications running and no requirement for the OS to page memory.

My personal experience of performance testing in Firefox is that it is highly unpredictable. Comparing two code algorithms by timing each produced different results if the order of testing is reversed. For example the first algorithm run first seemed to be faster, but if the second algorithm was run first it seemed to be faster. Or running the performance test multiple times produced quite varied results.

My response to these vagaries was to run performance tests multiple times, in different orders, and use a statistical measure of the outcomes as a *guide* to performance. The fastest time might indicate how fast code *can* run, the average might be a better real-world guide, and the slowest time, particularly if it is the first in a series, may be typical for code that runs only once.